# Numpy genfromtxt error : got extra columns instead of n many

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, python-3.x, numpy

```
import glob
import os
from numpy import genfromtxt

def main():
    path = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/InternshipWorks/Chhattisgarh')
    os.chdir(path)
    for file in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        print "Filename = ", file
        my_data = genfromtxt(file, delimiter = ',', dtype = str)
        print "Data Received" 
        Bindex, Iindex = 0, 0
        for j in range(len(my_data[0])):
            if Bindex == 0 and my_data[0,j] == 'B':
                Bindex = j
            if Iindex == 0 and my_data[0,j] == 'I':
                Iindex = j

if 1:
    main()
```

I got the following error while reading a csv file using genfromtxt from numpy using this code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "readcsvTest.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "readcsvTest.py", line 10, in main
    my_data = genfromtxt(file, delimiter = ',', dtype = str)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 1593, in genfromtxt
    raise ValueError(errmsg)
ValueError: Some errors were detected !
    Line #3 (got 15 columns instead of 14)
    Line #4 (got 15 columns instead of 14)
```

I crosschecked the csv file but it does not contain any such relevant errors.

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: What's on lines 3 and 4 of your input? Can you post those, too?

Comment: @SatadipSaha try changing for j in range(len(my_data[1]))

Comment: thats a normal csv file. I found the same problem is posted on https://www.kaggle.com/c/stumbleupon/forums/t/5480/genfromtxt-problem/29958  but found no satisfying answer

Comment: Do you have header lines in the csv? They would definitely cause problems. It's suggestive that the error is on lines 3/4.

Comment: @Srivatsan : same error still persists

Comment: Yeah I have header in the file. In fact I'm trying to locate the columns corresponding to header 'B' and 'I'

Comment: The code is not causing problems for all but few csv files

Comment: OK, so we don't have enough information to answer this. You have to look and see what's different about the particular csv files that are failing on the first 4 lines. Likely you have a comma in the data that shouldn't be there, though it could be some other special character. If you post an example of the first 4 lines of a csv that fails, that would probably help.

Comment: https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-ixjxJcyECaM/UwT-yybyaRI/AAAAAAAAARk/4PfwjHqZO3g/w346-h195/Screenshot+from+2014-02-20+00:25:09.png .. here is the link to a image of that csv file

Comment: Far too small to be readable, try again?

Comment: @JoanSmith : https://plus.google.com/photos/yourphotos?enfplm&hl=en&utm_source=lmnavbr&utm_medium=embd&utm_campaign=lrnmre&rtsl=1&pid=5982186353540098322&oid=111330358090427444209 .. is it fine?

Answer (score 0):

The image still isn't working, but I'm moving to answers since we're having an (unfortunately) extended discussion in the comments.

When you call genfromtxt, numpy assumes that every row will have the same number of columns as the first row in the file. So the problem could be in the header rows, in that you have more columns than expected,  or in the data rows below, that you have fewer.

The problem is almost certainly in one of the first four lines of the file that's failing to import. There's a few things that you could do to troubleshoot.

First, look really carefully at lines 1, 2, 3, and 4 in the failing file. Are there any extraneous commas? Do you expect there to be 14 columns or 15? Any special characters, like #, \, /, or *?

If you really don't see anything, try building a dtype for your genfromtxt import. The type will force genfromtxt to make sure the data is the way you intend. For example, if you have 15 columns, all filled with strings of length less than 40 characters, your dtype will be:

```
dt_str = ", ".join("S40")    
dt = np.dtype(dt_str)
```

Then use genfromtxt with a dtype argument:

```
my_data = genfromtxt(file, delimiter = ',', dtype = dt)
```

This should tell you which row in the file has the wrong number of columns in the error message. Then look closely at that row, and you should be able to find the problem.

Additionally, from the screenshots it looks like you're opening the csv in a spreadsheet editor. I find it useful to open as raw text for troubleshooting this kind of thing. So, use notepad or something to examine each relevant line.

Comment: Thanks @Joan Smith for the suggestion. But when I opened the data with csv module it worked fine. There are some serious issues with numpy module as other people also tracked it at Kaggle site link

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, for me every column besides the header-column had an additional '\t' (tab) at the end. Unfortunately this comes from another software that I can't change (Xilinx Chipscope ASCII / .prn exported files). It gave me errors like:

```
Line #2 (got 67 columns instead of 66)
...
Line #4095 (got 67 columns instead of 66)
Line #4096 (got 67 columns instead of 66)
Line #4097 (got 67 columns instead of 66)
```

My initial command was:

```
X = np.genfromtxt(source, delimiter='\t', names=True)
```

I tried *a lot*, and in the end my solution became the following:

```
with open(source, 'rb') as fh:
  csvreader = csv.reader(fh, delimiter='\t')
  fNames = csvreader.next()

X = np.genfromtxt(source, delimiter='\t', names=','.join(fNames), skip_header=1)
```

It seems some trouble to use `genfromtxt` and rather only using `csv.reader` could be cleaner/better. But when I started to try that, I had too much initial trouble when I wanted to generate structured arrays, so I didn't consider it further

**Additional Information:**

(for the people that might find this post because of the chipscope keywords)

I was converting every column *after the first* from hex-string to integer number and casting it float.
For this I had to additionally do this before `genfromtxt`, as it doesn't allow you to define converters for a range of columns:

```
conv_dict = { }
for i in range(1, len(fNames)):
  conv_dict[i] = lambda s: float( int(str(s), 16) )
```

And then call genfromtxt this way:

```
X = np.genfromtxt(source, delimiter='\t', names=','.join(fNames), skip_header=1, converters=conv_dict)
```